# Web service to retrieve URL from online streaming radio station?

Tags: streaming, radio

I am looking for a web service to retrieve the URL of an online radio streaming station.

This would be an example of such a station that I want to get the streaming URL for:

https://www.accuradio.com/channel/acoustic-blues/584/?name=Acoustic%20Blues&b0=Blues